# Html form not sending data

Tags: python, forms, cordova

I have a form action but it's not sending data and I don't know why, so I was hoping you could tell me why.

Here's my `form`:

```
<form method="post" action="http://myapp.herokuapp.com/test/url">
  <input placeholder="Name" type="text" name="user" maxlength="30">
  <input placeholder="Password" type="password" name="password">
  <input placeholder="email" type="text" name="mail">
  <input class="btn btn-register" type="submit" value="&iexcl;Register now!" />
</form>
```

And here's my back-end code (`Python`):

```
def test_1(request):
  return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({'post': request.POST, 'get': request.GET}))
```

What I get:

```
{"get": {}, "post": {}}
```

I have already an app working fine, and now I'm doing a `Phonegap` version of it.

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

When I change the url for `http://myapp.herokuapp.com/test/url/` I get this:

```
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
```

Comment: have you tried closing all your input tags /> ?

Comment: nope, but I'll try right now